# Discord.py - Detecting when a bot goes offline

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I have an event that tracks when a certain bot goes offline. (I host both bots) This is my code currently, I have not managed to get any output nor any traceback. Is there something I am missing? (I have turned on intents!)

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    if before.id == 777361919211732993:
      if after.status == discord.Status.offline:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(792485617954586634)
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "⚠️ PortalBot is offline!", description = "Recorded Downtime (start): " + str(timestamp.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) , color = 0xf03224)
        embed.add_field(name = "Restart Link", value = "-")
        await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Any tips or suggestions would help!

Comment: At first glance, your code looks okay to me. Maybe try adding `print(channel)` after you define it to see whether it's unable to access it?

Comment: the id is the bot id?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not *wrong*, however, there are a couple modifications I will describe after I explain why your bot is probably not able to detect the member update.

As of October 27, 2020, Discord updated their gateway by adding intents. The part that is most likely affecting your code, as seen in [this](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994) post, is quoted here:

### For bots that do not have the GUILD_MEMBERS intent --------

> If you do not need to do anything when a guild member joins, leaves, or is updated, you do NOT need the members intent. You cannot get a full member list to fill the cache, but in the majority of cases, a full member list is not necessary for building a persistent cache.

Without enabling the Privileged Gateway Intent of **Server Members Intent** in your bot's Developer Portal page, you won't be able to get these member updates. Also, after doing so, in your main bot class you will want to specify the intent in your `__init__` function, example:

```py
class Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        discord.Client.__init__(self, intents=discord.Intents(guilds=True, members=True))
```

Note: If your bot is in less than 100 guilds, you are perfectly fine to enable the privileged intent, but once you go over 100 guilds, you will need to get your bot verified (it will have a visual verified checkmark next to the bot tag) and get data whitelisting, [link](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412).

---

And now a couple of recommended modifications to your code:

1)
The current way you have it set up, it will always execute that code for any update that happens for that bot when it is displayed offline. This shouldn't be an issue, but it's better to be safe:
`if after.status == discord.Status.offline and before.status != discord.Status.offline:`

2)
Another modification which shouldn't normally be an issue, I would change `if before.id == 777361919211732993:` to `if after.id == 777361919211732993:` because the `before` variable is the cached version of the member and has a rare chance to be missing data, even the `id` attribute.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but I still don't get any output.

Comment: @SpaceTurtle0 Have you done all four of these: 1) Enable the Server Members Intent in your developer portal  2) Your bot is in less than 100 servers  3) Added the intents to your bot's main class  4) Made sure the bot ID and channel ID are both correct